# Which is best way of getting min and max date while comparing keys of 2 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am learning mysql, I have 2 tables, I have to compare table1 primary keys with table2 primary key, on successful match I need to get date min and max from table2 for this I have tried these commands, though I got result but it takes long time please let me know if there any good way to handle this case.

**date format is like this**

```
   mysql> select sdate from table2
   | 27-Apr-2000 11:50:00 AM |
   | 27-Apr-2000 10:20:00 AM |
   | 27-Apr-2000 08:30:00 AM |
   | 20-Jan-1999 12:00:00 PM |
```

**Commands I tried**

```
   mysql> select min(str_to_date(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) as date_min, max(str_to_date(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) as date_max from ( select distinct p.key1 as key1, p.key2 as key2 from table1 as p ) as T inner join table2 as m on T.key1 = m.key1 and T.key2 = m.key2 where m.sdate !='';
   +------------+------------+
   | date_min   | date_max   |
   +------------+------------+
   | 1989-02-24 | 2011-12-30 |
   +------------+------------+
   1 row in set, 11396 warnings (18.95 sec)


   mysql> select min(str_to_date(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) as date_min, max(str_to_date(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) as date_max from ( select p.key1 as key1, p.key2 as key2 from table1 as p ) as T inner join table2 as m on T.key1 = m.key1 and T.key2 = m.key2 where m.sdate !='';
   +------------+------------+
   | date_min   | date_max   |
   +------------+------------+
   | 1989-02-24 | 2011-12-30 |
   +------------+------------+
   1 row in set, 11442 warnings (18.78 sec)


   mysql> select min(str_to_date(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) as date_min, max(str_to_date(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) as date_max from table2 as m, table1 as p where p.key1 = m.key1 and p.key2 = m.key2 and m.sdate !='';
   +------------+------------+
   | date_min   | date_max   |
   +------------+------------+
   | 1989-02-24 | 2011-12-30 |
   +------------+------------+
   1 row in set, 11442 warnings (18.86 sec)

   mysql>
```

Comment: Try after the query to run the `SHOW WARNINGS\G` statement also refer to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html) for more information

Comment: Do you really intend for `key1` to be used for both comparisons in the queries?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: the third query does have a `key2=key2` predicate, the first two have a `key2=key1` predicate.

Comment: The "big rock" performance issue is that `sdate` column is not stored in a canonical format. MySQL cannot make effective use of an index range scan operation to locate the "smallest" and "largest" values. In the given format, we force the optimizer to evaluate a function on every flipping row in the table, and then to locate the smallest and largest values from that. If the `sdate` column was stored as `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` or as a VARCHAR in a canonical format, MySQL could make effective use of an available index.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . I quite disagree.  The issue here is the join between the two tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I agree that the `JOIN` could be a performance issue **if** (and we're just guessing here) `(key1,key2)` is not unique or nearly unique in `table1`, and if there is no suitable index available. The performance impact of the JOIN is really a matter of cardinality and distribution. Because if `(key1,key2)` is unique (or nearly unique) in `table1` AND there's a suitable index available, we wouldn't expect the `JOIN` operation to be a performance issue. A  large number of rows in `table2` would present a performance issue  absent an index to efficiently locate the MIN() and MAX().

Comment: We'd really need to see table definitions. (Is the `(key1,key2)` tuple really the `PRIMARY KEY` of `table1`? Is `(key1,key2)` the PRIMARY KEY of `table2`? The question says "compare table1 primary keys with table2 primary key". (Two of the queries in the question have predicates on table1.key1 only, the third query has predicates on table1.key1 and table1.key2. So we're kind of left wondering what the "primary key" of each table actually is.) EXPLAIN output of each query would also be of benefit.

Comment: Sorry its my fault mistyped while posting...

Comment: Actually table2 contains many columns like date, place etc, where if you combine key1 and key2 you will get unique values, and another table table1 contains key1, key2, serial, item_value,  I need to get uniq key1, key2 from table1 and then get corresponding date for these keys from table2 and then get date min and max

Comment: @user3637224: I'm not sure I'm understanding this correctly. Are you saying there's UNIQUE constraint on `table2(key1,key2)` AND there's a UNIQUE constraint on `table1(key1,key2)`. Are these the declared as the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table? Or, are there indexes on these columns?

Comment: @spencer7593 : Yes sir you are right, as a learner I don't know much about the technical terms

Comment: Warning problem is fixed with this format `'%d-%M-%Y %h:%i:%s %p'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the queries is able to make effective use of an index (ie. range scan operation) on the `VARCHAR` `sdate` column, because that column is "wrapped" in a function in the query. For optimum performance of queries of this form, ideally the `sdate` would be an actual MySQL `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype, or even a `VARCHAR` in canonical format. If that were the case, the optimizer would be able to make effective use of an index to quickly locate the "smallest" and "largest" date values, without a need to evaluate the `STR_TO_DATE` function for every flipping row in the table, and avoid the need for a sort operation to locate the "smallest" and "largest" values returned from the function.

With that (semi-rant) aside...

---

In the general case, to get a result equivalent to the first two queries in your question, a query of the form suggested in the answer from Gordon Linoff may be your best bet.

(We note the first two queries include a `key2=key1` predicates, the third query has a `key2=key2` predicate.)

If there are a large number of rows in `table2`, and if a large majority of those rows will "match" a row from `table1`, and there are relatively small number of distinct `(key1,key2)` values in `table2`, and if the `(key1,key2)` tuple is either unique or nearly unique in `table1`,

there's an outside chance that a query of this form may perform better:

```
SELECT MIN(q.sdate_min) AS date_min
     , MAX(q.sdate_max) AS date_max 
  FROM ( SELECT m.key1
              , m.key2
              , MIN(STR_TO_DATE(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) AS sdate_min
              , MAX(STR_TO_DATE(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) AS sdate_max
           FROM table2 m
          GROUP
             BY m.key1
              , m.key2
       ) q
  JOIN table1 t
    ON t.key1 = q.key1
   AND t.key2 = q.key2
```

To improve performance of the inline view query, you are going to want an index on `table2` with leading columns of `key1` and `key2` (in either order), and also including the `sdate` column. For example:

```
... ON table2 (key1, key2, sdate)
```

To improve performance of the `JOIN` operation, you are going to want an index on `table1` with `key1` and `key2` as the leading columns in the index. For example:

```
... ON table1 (key1,key2)
```

or

```
... ON table1 (key2,key1)
```

(This assumes you will be using predicates of the form in your third query i.e. key1=key1 and key2=key**2**

If you will be using predicates of the form  key1=key1 and key2=key**1**, then we'd adjust the query and indexes accordingly.

Comment: Note that the query in not likely to exhibit any performance improvement, and will likely be slower, if the `(key1,key2)` is the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) in both `table1` and `table2`. Absent the actual table definitions (which storage engine, cluster key, available indexes, etc.) and output from EXPLAIN, it's going to be difficult to make a particular recommendation; since we're just guessing at cardinality, distribution, uniqueness, number of rows,

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
select min(str_to_date(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) as date_min,
       max(str_to_date(m.sdate,'%d-%M-%Y')) as date_max
from table2 m
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t
              where t.key1 = m.key1 and t.key1 = m.key2
             );
```

Then, create an index on `table1(key1, key2)` for performance.

Comment: The question suggests that the PRIMARY KEY of `table1` is the `(key1,key2)` tuple. (We don't know for sure that's true; all we have to go on is the statement in the question "**compare table1 primary keys with table2 primary key**", and the queries in the question. The first two queries include table2.key2=table1.key **1** predicate (as does the query in this answer) but the third query instead has table2.key2=table1.key **2** predicate.  If this query returns the correct resultset (because the predicates are of the correct form), it could also include predicate **`AND m.key1=m.key2`**

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . Based on the fact that the use of `select distinct` in one of the subqueries affects the number of warnings, I don't think the OP is using the term "primary key" in the way that you and I would use it when talking to each other.